# System of equations solving for a b c d

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

[image]

Im doing a problem that requires partial fractions, Im having trouble figuring out how to solve for a b c and d.

How do i solve for each letter? Can i just take 2 at a time and try to solve for a letter?

Comment: You have a 4x4 matrix. Are you familiar with Gaussian elimination - row reduced echelon form? You should get $a = -7/16,   b = -1/4,   c = 2,   d = -25/16$

Comment: You did not state the original problem, and it is not easy to reconstruct it. If you give the original, someone probably will almost immediately show you how to do solve it more efficiently, using fewer equations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use row-reduce an augmented matrix to RREF form and get values for $A,B,C,D$.

Assuming that your equations are correct,
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & -4 &8 \\
    -7& 1 &-5 & 5 & -15\\
    6 &-6 & 3 & -2 & 8\\
  \end{array}\right]
$$
$$\rightarrow   \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-7}{16} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-1}{4} \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{-25}{16}\\
  \end{array}\right]$$

i.e. $A=\frac{-7}{16},B=\frac{-1}{4},C=2,D=\frac{-25}{16}$ (assuming I didn't make a mistake).

Note: Considering it involves so many factors, you might consider using the **"cover-up rule"**.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know about matrices and row-reduction, you can solve the first equation for $A$ in terms of $C$ and $D$; solve the second equation for $B$ in terms of $C$ and $D$; then subtitute in for $A$ and $B$ in the third and fourth equations. That will give you two equations in the two unknowns $C$ and $D$ --- can you handle that?

EDIT: In further detail, first equation becomes $$A=-C-D;$$ second equation becomes $$B=8-C+4D;$$ third equation becomes $$-15=-7(-C-D)+(8-C+4D)-5C+5D;\tag1$$ fourth equation becomes $$8=6(-C-D)-6(8-C+4D)+3C-2D.\tag2$$ A bit of algebra now gets (1) and (2) to look like two linear equations in two unknowns, and you're on your way.